# Flutter: The named parameter 'decoration' isn't defined

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I'm trying to code a bar for the top of my app and I'm getting an error saying "The named parameter 'decoration' isn't defined."

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GradientAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final double barHeight = 66.0;

  GradientAppBar(this.title);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double statusBarHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;

    return new Container(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: statusBarHeight),
      height: statusBarHeight + barHeight,
      child: new Center(
        child: new Text(title,
            style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                fontSize: 36.0)),
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          gradient: new LinearGradient(
              colors: [const Color(0xFF3366FF), const Color(0xFF00CCFF)],
              begin: const FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
              end: const FractionalOffset(0.5, 0.0),
              stops: [0.0, 0.5],
              tileMode: TileMode.clamp),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`decoration` property is from `Container` not from `Center` widget, so just move it.

```
     return new Container(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: statusBarHeight),
          height: statusBarHeight + barHeight,
          child: new Center(
            child: new Text(title,
                style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    fontSize: 36.0)),
          ),

            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              gradient: new LinearGradient(
                  colors: [const Color(0xFF3366FF), const Color(0xFF00CCFF)],
                  begin: const FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
                  end: const FractionalOffset(0.5, 0.0),
                  stops: [0.0, 0.5],
                  tileMode: TileMode.clamp),
            ),
        );
```

Comment: Thank you so much my friend I could not work it out at all as I am new to flutter.

Comment: Can I have it insde Meterial Widget @edpor